# Unified directory tree walking for local files, ftp, http in python

Tags: python, ftp, beautifulsoup, os.walk

In my [testkernel](https://gist.github.com/1897943) program I'd like to walk directory trees via a variety of protocols.  What I think I want is something like `os.walk`, but which works for ftp, and for typical http directory listings also (like http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/).  This is in the spirit of [openanything.py](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/index.html)

For FTP walking I found several options, including [ftptool](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftptool/0.5.1), and the [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation#iteration-over-directories) module which has the advantage of being in Ubuntu.  I've already implemented my own very simple recursive walk of http directory listings, using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  But before I combine them together with `os.walk`, I wonder if it has been done already.

I know the semantics of http walking are not well-defined like they are for file systems and ftp, so I guess I'll have to guess that directories are indicated by a URL with a trailing slash which extends the URL of the directory.  And I'll have to be careful to avoid infinite walks.  But even for a subset of os.walk (e.g. only topdown), this sort of thing seems useful.

Has this been done?  Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I wrote a piece of code which actually walks through web directories and downloads the files:
(although this piece code could need improvement like image downloading, pdf download etc), 
but anyway here is the source/module:

[Download files and dirs recursively from a remote source](http://www.bunkahle.com/Python/download_url_dirs.py)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to migrate from the existing http-only code I pointed to, to a more generic approach that leverages the os.walk interface, so it can be unified with ftp, local files etc.